# Sql changing dob to age, then displaying the youngest 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains information about a student

i need a way in that i can take their dob and change it into years (i.e 02/10/94/ = 21) and then display only the youngest 3 with the age in years.

The 2 columns that i assume that will be needed for this are called name and DOB

if someone could help me out i'd be greatly appreciative

Comment: use this `SELECT dob FROM student ORDER BY dob ASC LIMIT 3`

Comment: There is nothing on google for how to return only the lowest three values from a result set and how to find the difference in years between a date and right now?

Comment: Well, you're posing the question back to front. The youngest 3 are simply the 3 born most recently. That's easy (except you may want to think about ties). Next, you need to calculate the age of those. That's (ever so slightly) trickier, but there are hundreds of examples out there. Of course dob would be 1994/02/15.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this

```
select YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob)  as age 
FROM student 
order by age limit 3;
```

Or

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob)/365 AS age
FROM student 
order by age limit 3;
```

Are not exact because the year is not ever 365 day .. but could be useful

Comment: Actually, you should also select the `age in days` and sort by that.